# The name 'txtname' doesn't exist in the current context

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I am using visual studio 2010. When i run the asp page it shows the errors `"The name 'txtname' doest not exists in the current context"`. I am new in C# programming needs help.
I am using all the defined variables but i am still confused why it is giving errors.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Net;
namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class contactus : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                //Create the msg object to be sent
                MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
                //Add your email address to the recipients
                msg.To.Add("myinfo@yahoo.com");
                //Configure the address we are sending the mail from
                MailAddress address = new MailAddress("abc@gmail.com");
                msg.From = address;
                //Append their name in the beginning of the subject
                msg.Subject = txtName.Text + " :  " + txtName1.Text;
                msg.Body = txtMessage.Text;

                //Configure an SmtpClient to send the mail.
                SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
                client.EnableSsl = true; //only enable this if your provider requires it
                //Setup credentials to login to our sender email address ("UserName", "Password")
                NetworkCredential credentials = new NetworkCredential("abc@gmail.com", "paswword");
                client.Credentials = credentials;

                //Send the msg
                client.Send(msg);

                //Display some feedback to the user to let them know it was sent
                lblResult.Text = "Your email has been received, you will be contacted soon by our representative if required.";

                //Clear the form
                txtName.Text = "";
                txtName1.Text = "";
                txtMessage.Text = "";
            }
            catch
            {
                //If the message failed at some point, let the user know
                lblResult.Text = "Your message failed to send, please try again.";
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: txtName does not exist **in the current context**. That's the key part of the error message. It's defined perhaps, but from that line of code it does not know of its existence.

Comment: Is the textbox a server-side control? Is ViewState enabled for it?

Comment: msg.Subject = txtName.Text

Here it is defined. Look

Comment: Where is `txtName` defined initially ?
Use `Find All` and look for "txtName = new"

Comment: <!-- Name -->
    <tr>
        <td align="center" class="style16">
            <strong>Name:</strong></td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" CssClass="tb6"
                            runat="server"
                            Columns="50" Width="301px"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
    </tr>
 
    <!-- Subject -->

Comment: Can you please post your full aspx page?

Comment: `msg.Subject = txtName.Text` doesn't define `txtName`, it uses it to set something else. You need to define it before that.

Answer (score 2):

When .cs file name in Code behind attribute does not match , then only this kind of error can occur.

Check your code behind file name and Inherits property on the `@Page directive`, make sure they both match.

Or it seems that you have copy and pasted the control or code related to it.

This often creates problem in `designer` file.

You can delete that textbox and once again drag-drop it on your app from `toolbar`

Comment: Yes that is one big source of problems.

Comment: I dont know why OP is not posting aspx code, it will clear out many things

Answer (score 0):

add `runat="server"` in the txtName control if it is a regular html control.

Comment: I have already added. It is asp content type.

   <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" CssClass="tb6"
                            runat="server"
                            Columns="50" Width="301px"></asp:TextBox>

Answer (score 0):

I know this is and old question. I got the same problem after copying few divs in a seperate place. This might be useful to anyone in future. Just remove **runat="server"** attribute of the relevenat tag and again insert it. It worked for me 100%.